# Get Observable value if the Observable is true, otherwise print a string

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Inside a template I have this code:

```
<app-name val="{{ (observable$ | async)?.field > 0 || "No field" }}"
```

I want to get the value of the properties "**field**" of the Observable if "**field**" is > 0.

If **"field"** isn't > 0, I want to print "No field".

So far, with that code I get **"true"** (instead of field value) when field is > 0, and I get, correctly,"No field" if field isn't > 0.
I miss something about this synthax.

Thank you

Comment: Why not have this logic in a function in your component? Just map it to whatever value and have your template only resolve the observable. In my opinion this makes it incredibly difficult to read and traverse the code base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you just want to fix the conditional, something like this:

```html
<app-name val="{{ (observable$ | async)?.field > 0 ? (observable$ | async)?.field : "No field" }}"
```

This will make 2 calls though but you can prevent it by adding these to your observable:

```js
observable$.pipe(
  publishReplay(1),
  refCount()
)
```

2. You can tidy it up a little bit like this:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="observable$ | async as observable">
  <app-name val="{{ observable?.field > 0 ? observable.field : 'No field' }}">
  </app-name>
</ng-container>
```

3. or if you want to handle it in the component:

```html
<app-name val="{{ observable$ | async }}"
```

```js
observable$.pipe(
  map((res) => {
    return res.field > 0 ? res.field : "No field";
  })
)
```

Comment: thank for the response. Actually the first code you wrote was my original code. The problem was that way I made 2 subscription. I've been told there a way to write code, inside a template, avoiding to call 2 subscribe.

Comment: @Matt yep, you can use the other ways I've written. I'll update the 2 call part as well

Comment: With the example n. 2 there aren't two subscriptions to the observable. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes both 2 and 3 will result in only 1 subscription. I've updated my first approach too tho, so that will also be 1 subscription now (it will be 2 but it will be cached so it will return the same response).

Answer (score 1):

Without the conditional logic in the template, it can be achieved by creating a property in the component.

In the template:

```html
<app-name [val]="field"></app-name> <!-- binding to the property-->
```

In the component:

```js
  // the field will be updated when the observable completes
  private _field = -1;

  // depending on the internal logic, 
  // the subscription might be invoked in a lifecycle method or elsewhere:
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.observable$.subscribe((value: number) => this._field = value);
  }

  public get field(): number | string {
    return this._field > 0 ? this._field : 'No field';
  }
```